# What can I use in core-pattern to dump a core and nothing else?

Tags: linux, gdb

I'm currently working on a weird GNU chroot environment, that uses abrt-hook-ccpp for the original system to dump cores, however the environment I'm in does not have that utility.

systemd-coredump does not exist on the chrooted environment either, so it is not an option.

I would like to access a core file. I can drop out of chroot and remotely copy it somewhere else for analysis, and I need little to no information as I know when and where the core is being created.

What's the simplest, most basic core-pattern file I can create to dump the core into the current (or any) directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Literally just `core`. Anything that is *not* prefixed by `|` is used as a file name (absolute within the chroot, or relative to the working directory). See [core(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/core.5.html) for more details.

Note that when dumps are written directly to a file (not piped), the RLIMIT_CORE ulimit of the crashing process will be enforced – if it's zero, no core file will be created.

You can also create a custom handler script for `|`-format patterns (e.g. you could make "abrt-hook-ccpp" a regular bash script that runs `cat > /tmp/core`); the handler only needs to read the dump from its stdin and save it somewhere. In this case, RLIMIT_CORE is not enforced.

Comment: This is perfect - looks like I'll still have to build core from source, but it gets me somewhere easier

Comment: Build what from source? There's no program named "core" involved here. The string "core" is the actual name of your core-dump file.

Comment: I misunderstood the man entry - I had assumed core was a program.

Answer (score 0):

If your system is configured to send the core to the abrt (Automated Bug Reporting Tool), you may find it in `/var/cache/abrt`. Check also `/var/crash`.

Reference :
[Core dumped, but core file is not in the current directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065912/core-dumped-but-core-file-is-not-in-the-current-directory)

Comment: `/system` is bind-linked to the running kernel, which uses `abrt`, but the chrooted environment does not have abrt, so the core is never being created. The problem is not finding where `abrt` puts the core, it's finding an alternative that I can be certain will work on the barebones chrooted system